# PHP cookie is being auto delete or not being set on frequent AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I got a weird situation from yesterday, and it is really embarrassing that cookie is not being set.

Scenario:

1) system have AJAX call to check user session if it is alive or not while user is not doing any activity on page.

2) Request sent to server side every minute to check user session
if user is idle for specific minutes it send request to expire session to logout page.

3) On logout page it expire session because of inactivity and set cookie for record, when user re-enter credentials it will refresh session where it left.

Problem is.
Cookie not being set while I had tried following scenarios.
using all parameters

```
setcookie("config_transactionID", $_SESSION['cableTransactionID'], $expire,'/', 'http://domain.com');
```

used root path

```
setcookie("config_transactionID", $sessionValue, $expire,'/');
```

used basic paramters.

```
setcookie("config_transactionID", $_SESSION['cableTransactionID'], $expire);
```

Tried header_remove too, to remove all headers before setting cookie.

used some static content to set cookie if it is being set or not.
but system returns

```
 set_cookie returns: bool(true)
```

Code which send request to back end

```
function expireSession(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: SiteVars.siteUrl+"Logout.php?sess=idle",
    data:{test:"test"},

    success: function(data)
    {

    }//

 });//

}
```

Comment: Is the AJAX calling a script on the same domain as the PHP script was run from?

Comment: Can you please tell me if you are sending a frequent request to this script ?

Comment: @ShahRukh mentioned in following point "2) Request sent to server side every minute to check user session if user is idle for specific minutes it send request to expire session to logout page."

Comment: @BasitMunir then I think the cookie set at 1st request of from session value and then on 2nd request session value is null so that it makes the cookie null, please try to add a check for session set, before you set the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shah Rukh suggestion worked for me. problem with the scrip was frequent session expiry requests.  Repetitive session expiry requests were resetting cookie value with NULL (while session was expired after first one).

I added a check where I was setting a cookie and additionally added random string to actual value to make sure it will never be empty.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['config_transactionID'])){

    $expire = time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
    $transaction = base64_encode($_SESSION['cableTransactionID'].'--'.md5(rand(999,9999)));
    $var = setcookie("config_transactionID", $transaction, time()+ (60*60*24*30));

}
```